# Django search html form

Tags: python, django, html, search

I want to make a search form on my django site.
So I just create a product search list:

```
class ProductSearchListView(ProductList):
    """
    Display a Product List page filtered by the search query
    """
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(ProductSearchListView, self).get_queryset()

        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            query_list = query.split()
            result = result.filter(
                reduce(
                    operator.and_,
                    (Q(nome__icontains=q) for q in query_list)
                ) |
                reduce(
                    operator.and_,
                    (Q(categoria__icontains=q) for q in query_list)
                )
            )

        return result
```

In my HTML I want to have a box to make an easy search and, clicking ENTER, the user should see a list of all products.

```
<form id="searchform" action="{% do something %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <input .../>
</form>

{% if list_of_products_returned_from_search == null %}
   <div ...>
      None product found.
   </div>
{% elif products exists %}
   {% for product in products %}
      Name: {{product.name}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So what is the question ? `<input type="submit" ` should handle the enter key press

Comment: The question is "How to call the query_set" method in the html?

Comment: @user2732966 depends on how it's saved in the context. What's in ProductList?

Comment: I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem.

First, I create a function in views.py:

```
def return_home(request):
    lista_de_produtos = Produto.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        query_list = query.split()
        lista_de_produtos = lista_de_produtos.filter(nome__icontains=query)


    context = {
        "produtos": lista_de_produtos,
    }
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context)
```

After, I write the HTML code:

```
                     {% if produtos %}
                            <ul id="flexiselDemo3">
                        {% for produto in produtos %}
                                <li>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 biseller-column">
                                        <a href="single.html">
                                            <img src="{{produto.foto}}"/>
                                            <span class="price">R&#36; {{produto.preco}}</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="ad-info">
                                            <h5>{{produto.nome}}</h5>
                                            <span>{{produto.descricao_curta}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                  {% else %}
                  <p id="flexiseDemo3">
                     Nenhum produto encontrado!
                  </p>
                  {% endif %}
```

Thank you!